Hangfire App as windows service fails to start
I have a Hangfire app(.Net 8) that i tried to host in windows server as windows service, but it's fails to start. The server already host few other HF apps as windows service & there is no problem with those.
I thought the issue with the codebase of my app & tried a sample from this Github repo. The app use SQL Lite instead of SQL Server as backend for the Hangfire service.
I created a window service with below command to run the sample Hangfire app in my local system.
sc create "Hangfire Service - test4" binPath= "C:\Users\pall\Downloads\Hangfire.Storage.SQLite-master\Hangfire.Storage.SQLite-master\src\samples\WebSample\bin\Release\net8.0\WebSample.exe"

When i start the service of sample app in local system, i get the same below error that i get in server.

The event viewer shows timeout error.
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Hangfire Service - test4 service to connect.

However if i run the app direct(by running .exe) there's no issue.
I need to run this app as windows service so that i can view the HF dashboard in a webapp.
What am i doing wrong here?

Windows Services typically run under the LocalSystem, NetworkService, or a specific user account. Make sure the service account has the necessary permissions to your SQLServer, Or change service account.
for changing service account run service.msc, right click on your service and select properties, go to the log on tab and select this account then specify a user with appropriate permissions.

the sample hangfire app i hosted in my local system as windows service, without any service account. I used this sample to check to avoid the permission problems with service account. However i added my creds in Logon tab of the win service properties. I still get same issue.
